# Plotly: Joining plots by subplots

Tags: python, plotly, subplot

I have a dataframe, and I can do three different plots (a bar, stacked bars and a line plot) but I need make only one figure using subplots. Is it possible?

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = pd.DataFrame([['A',0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,125,0.032],
                     ['B',0.20,0.40,0.15,0.25,175,0.054],
                     ['C',0.25,0.25,0.30,0.20,192,0.065]])
data.columns = ['GROUP','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','SALES','IND']
data = data.set_index('GROUP')
data

fig1 = px.bar(data['SALES'], text_auto=True)
fig1.show()

fig2 = px.bar(data[['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4']])
fig2.show()

fig3 = px.line(data['IND'])
fig3.show()type here
```

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTLqv.png)

I just can add two plots (the bar and line ones) but I can't add the stacked bars

I tried this:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data['SALES'])
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df1['GROUP'],y=df1['SALES']),1,1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data['IND'])
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2['GROUP'],y=df2['IND']),2,1)

fig.show()
```

[my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEUwq.png)

Comment: Is your goal to add a stacked graph next to the first bar chart?

Comment: yes, or at the last

Answer (score 0):

Since the x-axis is a categorical variable, the bars and stacked bars overlap. A third way to avoid this is to data frame and change the x-axis to `[0,1,2]` and `[0.5,1.5,2.5]` for the stacked graph to avoid overlap. At the same time, the second y-axis is used to allow reading the values. Finally, the x-axis scale of the first graph is changed to the value and variable name at the midpoint between the two graphs. There may be an easier way than my method.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}],[{"secondary_y": False}]])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data['SALES'])
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[0,1,2], y=df1['SALES'], width=0.48, name='SALES'),1,1)#df1['GROUP']

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data[['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4']])
df3.reset_index(inplace=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[0.5,1.5,2.5], y=df3['Q1'], width=0.480, name='Q1'),1,1,secondary_y=True)#df3['GROUP']
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[0.5,1.5,2.5], y=df3['Q2'], width=0.480, name='Q2'),1,1,secondary_y=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[0.5,1.5,2.5], y=df3['Q3'], width=0.480, name='Q3'),1,1,secondary_y=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[0.5,1.5,2.5], y=df3['Q4'], width=0.480, name='Q4'),1,1,secondary_y=True)
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=[0.25,1.25,2.25], ticktext=['A','B','C'], row=1, col=1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data['IND'])
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2['GROUP'],y=df2['IND'], name='IND'),2,1)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I see that my response helped you. In addition, see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer

My final code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data['SALES'])
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1,
                    subplot_titles=('Bar', 'Stacked Bars', 'Line'))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data['SALES'])
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df1['GROUP'], y=df1['SALES'], name='SALES'),1,1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data[['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4']])
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df1['GROUP'], y=df2['Q1'], name='Q1'),2,1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df1['GROUP'], y=df2['Q2'], name='Q2'),2,1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df1['GROUP'], y=df2['Q3'], name='Q3'),2,1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df1['GROUP'], y=df2['Q4'], name='Q4'),2,1)
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data['IND'])
df3.reset_index(inplace=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df3['GROUP'],y=df3['IND']),3,1)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=600, showlegend=False, title_text='Main Title')

fig.show()
```

The result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvERe.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).